# What arguments should I pass to input_shape parameter of LSTM function in Keras?

Tags: keras, lstm, model-selection, forecasting

My dataset has 2944424 rows and 6 columns. I am using an LSTM in Keras to forecast taxi demand. I am having problem with the `input_shape` parameter of the LSTM.

It gives the error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_15_input to have 3 dimension
```

Comment: Add your model code so that people can understand the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input should be of shape (batch size, number of steps, features). See the following for details:

https://machinelearningmastery.com/reshape-input-data-long-short-term-memory-networks-keras/

Answer (score 0):

Following example shows that by **printing shape of your train data** you can pass the right value to `input_shape()`. Also it depends you want to feed your data in 2D or another way. As it can be seen in snippet:

`trainX.shape[1]`=10

`trainX.shape[2]`=1440

and in output based on test shape `Dense(units = 960)`

```py
#Shape of train and test data
trainX, testX, trainY, testY = train_test_split(trainX,trainY, test_size=0.2 , shuffle=False)
print("train size: {}".format(trainX.shape))
print("train Label size: {}".format(trainY.shape))
print("test size: {}".format(testX.shape))
print("test Label size: {}".format(testY.shape))
#train size: (23, 10, 1440)
#train Label size: (23, 960)
#test size: (6, 10, 1440)
#test Label size: (6, 960)

# create and fit the Simple LSTM model 

#model_LSTM = Sequential()
model_LSTM.add(LSTM(units = 1440, input_shape=(trainX.shape[1], trainX.shape[2])))
model_LSTM.add(Dense(units = 960))
```

**Edit:** Following tips based on this [example](https://machinelearningmastery.com/reshape-input-data-long-short-term-memory-networks-keras/) to help you when preparing your input data for LSTMs:

- The LSTM input layer must be 3D.
- The meaning of the 3 input dimensions are: samples, time steps, and features.
- The LSTM input layer is defined by the `input_shape` argument on the first hidden layer.
- The `input_shape` argument takes a tuple of two values that define the number of time steps and features.
- The number of samples is assumed to be 1 or more.
- The `reshape()` function on NumPy arrays can be used to reshape your 1D or 2D data to be 3D.
- The `reshape()` function takes a tuple as an argument that defines the new shape.

Comment: Trying your solution it says `IndexError: tuple index out of range`.

Comment: I updated the answer but would you share your code so that we can have a look!?

Comment: `model.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu', input_shape=(3, 1)))` This is throwing error. I am not getting that how should I change that?

Comment: I guess that your input_shape is not right and you can't pass the right dimension. Plz update your question by leaving your complete code including dataset and data split and so on.